# FIR Filter 3dB Frequency

Tags: lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response, frequency-response

I am new to signal processing and I want to calculate the 3 dB - cut off frequency of this FIR filter, which has the following transfer function:

[image: Transfer function]

For the evaluation i need to replace the z with [image] and set the squared magnitude equal to 1/2.

[image]

[image]

But the problem is when I want to solve this for omega zero is the result. My question is what am I doing wrong here, or is something missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach:

1. The expression $\displaystyle\frac{1+z^{-1}}{2}$ is the transfer function $H(z)$, NOT its magnitude $|H(z)|$.
2. Consequently, the expression $\displaystyle \frac{1+e^{-j\Omega}}{2}$ is the complex frequency response $H(e^{j\Omega})$, not its magnitude.

So now you have to compute the squared magnitude of $H(e^{j\Omega})$ and set it equal to $\frac12$. This is a basic exercise in complex numbers, so I trust that you can take it from here.

For some magical reason, the right half of you last equation is actually the final correct equation, even though everything before it is wrong. If you think about it for a while, you should figure out that the solution is given by

$$\cos(\Omega_c)=0\tag{1}$$

which certainly does not imply that $\Omega_c=0$. What is it that it *does* imply?